# Disable replacing spaces to dashes when upload file [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to disable replacing spaces to dashes in Wordpress when uploading a file?
I have website with mp3 files, and for example I have file:

**`"Author - Track Title (Original Mix).mp3"`**
and after upload it converts into

```
"Author-Track-Title-(Original-Mix).mp3"
```

I know that is because security reasons, but on other websites when you download a file it can be downloaded with normal filename without DASHES. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should ***never*** have not-safe-filenames in your system, ever. Odd cases *will appear* where file "magically" dont exist, filename functions could act weird, URLs get harder to create, et cetera.
**TL;DR: Don't do it like that**.

When a user uploads a file, convert the filename to something safe, eg a random string, but also **store the original filename in your database**. Then when you present it back to the user, you can set the headers/filename for the download to that stored name, while internally you have a nice safe filename.

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are replaced in wordpress, because some applications won't open them such as in the case of old XP and probably other applications, and they are not valid in the url.

Sometimes you come across the issue of backslashes, and this is normally down to security to stop code injection attacks.

As a solution you could try this one from the 'Make wordpress Core' website - but this could always fail in an update of wordpress!!!

```
if ( '' == $url )
                 return $url;
        $url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);
     $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);
         if ( 0 !== stripos( $url, 'mailto:' ) ) {
                 $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
                 $url = _deep_replace($strip, $url);
         }

         $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);
         /* If the URL doesn't appear to contain a scheme, we
          * presume it needs http:// appended (unless a relative
```

Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/23605/23605.diff